# What does 前が遅れているとのことで mean exactly?

Tags: meaning

Context:

> 今日は午前中に引っ越し業者がくる予定だったけど、**前が遅れているとのことで**午後から荷物を受け取ることになりました。荷物は比較的少なかったので引っ越し自体は30分で終わり、ただ荷解きに2時間かかりました。

I don't quite understand what "前が遅れているとのことで" means. May I ask two questions about this phrase?

1. What does "前" refer to? The previous task of the movers or something else?
2. What exactly does "とのことで" mean? I guess it basically means "because"? Is "と" used to nominalize "前が遅れている"?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, this 前 refers to the mover's prior moving engagement of the day.
2. It's [とのことだ](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A0-to-iu-koto-da-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AE%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A0-to-no-koto-da-meaning/), but it's in its [te-form (for reason)](https://www.learn-japanese-adventure.com/te-form-cause-reason.html).

> 前が遅れている**とのことで**...
>
> **since they said** their previous job was running late, ...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the useful links. But may I ask, why "とのことだ" here  doesn't mean "conclusion"? If it means "hearsay", as you said, it implies that the author contacted the movers before they arrived, and if it means "conclusion", I think it simply describes the results that the movers were late. Is it because this is "te-form"?

Comment: @Theseus The sentence means that the mover called the author and told they'd be late. And I don't know when とのことだ can express "conclusion" in the first place...

Comment: @Theseus By "in the first place", I was trying to say [this](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%8A%91) :)

Comment: Thanks again for pointing out my misunderstanding! And may I ask, what place does "the first place" refer to? (I just mistakenly deleted the part of comment) Does it need a basis or an evidence when "とのことだ" express "conclusion"?

Comment: @Theseus I don't know, ["in the first place" is an English idiom](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/in-the-first-place), not Japanese.

Comment: Sorry, I had misread about [とのことだ](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A0-to-iu-koto-da-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AE%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A0-to-no-koto-da-meaning/) , I guess that "ということだ" can mean "conclusion", but not "とのことだ", right?